# What is the name for the valve that can fully control the flow between 3 points?

Tags: valve

I'm looking for a valve that has four states redirecting the water flow as such:
[image: STATE DIAGRAM]

(Valve is positioned at the junction of the three pipes)

What is the name for the valve that does this? 3-way or 4-way?

Answer (score 3):

Its a 3 way valve.  For example from [How Does A 3-Way Ball Valve Work](https://www.xhval.com/how-does-a-3-way-ball-valve-work/)

[image]

Note its not my site, just giving it credit for the image.